# Stream/Byte array to filename/extention/content type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need content-type(or extension or filename) of a file binary. Then feed to AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.File method

```
byte[] result = Repository.GetFile(Id);
if (result == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(result);
return File(stream , "application/pdf");
```

The code works fine only for pdf files. Unfortunately, my files have various extensions.

Comment: The whole reason we need content types separate from the file data is because you cannot (100% reliably) derive the former from the latter. Any of a variety of markup languages derived from XML, for example, are still XML. But whether they should be delivered as `application/xml` or `application/xhtml+xml` (or whetever) are semantics not inherent in the bytes of the file.

Comment: Store the MIME type in your `Repository` and retrieve it when needed.

Comment: FWIW, it's inefficient to create a memory stream from an existing byte array. You're basically just copying the data into memory twice. the `File` method can take a byte array directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the extension, you can probably get the mime type from that. ASP.NET Core actually has something built in to the Static Files middleware that you can use:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
var contentType = provider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out var type)
    ? type
    : "application/octet-stream";

return File(stream, contentType);
```

Other than that, Damien is correct in the comments, you cannot determine a mime type from byte data alone.